# Non-nullhomologous incompressible tori in finite covers of 3-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

I'm interested in proving the following claim:

**Lemma:** *Let $M$ be an aspherical, closed 3-manifold which is not hyperbolic. Then, there exists a finite cover $M'$ of $M$ and an incompressible embedded torus $T$ in $M'$, such that $T$ is non-nullhomologous in $M'$.*

I'm aware that if $M$ is Seifert fibered, then there exists a finite cover $M'$ of $M$ such that $M'$ is a circle bundle over a surface. I would like to say that we can take a further finite cover $M''$ which is a circle bundle over a surface $F$, where $F$ contains an embedded non-separating curve $\gamma$. Then the torus $T$ in $M''$ corresponding to the curve $\gamma$ is non-separating and thus non-nullhomologous.

If the above is correct, then it suffices to prove the Lemma in the case where the JSJ-decomposition of $M$ does not contain any Seifert fibered pieces. However, here I am stuck.

Comment: Since the tori in the JSJ decomposition are by definition incompressible, it seems we can reduce to the case where the $3$-manifold is geometric, no?

Comment: It’s possible, however, that the tori in the JSJ decomposition are all nullhomologous

Comment: Can you do something like Van Kampen? (as long as the pieces have non-trivial $\pi_{1}$) it seems it will work alot of the time (although I can't prove that). Is there some example where the JSJ tori are null-homologous?

Comment: The tori are nullhomologous exactly when they are separating in the 3-manifold. How do you suggest I should apply Van Kampen in this situation?

Comment: I am now not so sure anymore sorry.  Btw, It seems that there is a proof also for Sol $3$-manifolds. Take a finite cover w,hich is a $T^2$-bundle over $S^1$. Then, a $T^{2}$-fibre of the bundle is not seperating and incompressible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true but the proof is somewhat long. You can extract it from the proof of the main result in

*Hempel, John*, Residual finiteness for 3-manifolds, Combinatorial group theory and topology, Sel. Pap. Conf., Alta/Utah 1984, Ann. Math. Stud. 111, 379-396 (1987). [ZBL0772.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0772.57002).

Note that the paper operates under the "Haken" assumption, but it is only to ensure that Thurston's Geometrization Conjecture applies to the class of manifolds under consideration. Now, it's not a conjecture but a theorem (due to Perelman).